# Saving html data to .xlsx using JS

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I am having trouble figuring out how to use JS(java script) to save data inputted into a html page to a .xlsx file.
I need the file to be able to take a users name email and phone number and then once the submit button is pressed i need it to save the users input into a .xlsx file with the first 3 letters of there name and the first 3 numbers of there phone number (after area code) being the name of the file.
How do i do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-Test_2.css">
    <title>Pre Enrolment Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="regform">
        <h1><center><u><b>Pre Enrolment Form</b></u></center></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    
        <form method="POST">
            <h2><center><u>Student Information</u></center></h2>
            <div id="name">
                <center><input class="firstname" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" size="25">
                <input class="lastname" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" size="25"></center>
            </div>
            
                <br><center><input class="entry" type="text" name="entry" placeholder="Year Of Entry" size="25">
                <input class="s-email" type="email" name="s-email" placeholder="Student Email" size="25"></center>
                <br><center><input class="dob" type="text" name="dob" placeholder="Student's DOB (dd/mm/yyyy)" size="25">
                <input class="address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" size="25"></center>
                <br><center><input class="school" type="text" name="school" placeholder="Current School" size="25">
                <input class="school-contact" type="email" name="school-contact" placeholder="Contact Person At That School" size="25"></center>
    
            <center><h3 class="pathway"><u>Pathway Interests</u></h3>
                <select class="option" name="subject">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--Choose option--</option>
                <option>VCE/Mainstream</option>
                <option>ACE</option>
            </select></center>
            
            <center><h3 id="enrolled?"><u>Currently Enrolled?</u></h3>
            <label class="enrolled?">
                <input class="yes" type="radio" name="radiobtn"
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                Yes
            </label>
            
            <label class="enrolled?">
                <input class="no" type="radio" name="radiobtn">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                No
            </label></center>
                
                <h2><center><u>Parent/Guardian Information</u></center></h2>
                <br><center><input class="pg-fname" type="text" name="pg-fname" placeholder="Parent/Guardian First Name" size="25">
                <input class="pg-lname" type="text" name="pg-lname" placeholder="Parent/Guardian Last Name" size="25"></center>
                <br><center><input class="p-email" type="email" type="text" name="p-email" placeholder="Email Address" size="25">
                <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" size="25"></center>
                
            <center><h3 class="how-did-you-hear-about-SDC"><u>How Did You Hear About Sunbury Downs College?</u></h3>
                <select class="option2" name="how">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">--Choose Option--</option>
                <option>Website</option>
                <option>Facebook</option>
                <option>Instagram</option>
                <option>Advertisement</option>
                <option>Primary School</option>
                <option>Word Of Mouth</option>
                <option>Sign</option>
            </select></center>
                
                
            <center><h3 id="siblings?"><u>Do you have any siblings here?</u></h3>
            <label class="siblings?">
                <input class="yes" type="radio" name="radiobtn2">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                Yes
            </label>
            
            <label class="siblings?">
                <input class="no" type="radio" name="radiobtn2">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                No
            </label></center>
    
            <br><center><button class="register" type="submit" style="height:50px; width:300px; font-size:20px">Submit</button></center>
    
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*Is this even possible*" Most anything is possible in software with enough time, money, and resources. As such, questions in this format aren't good fits for Stack Overflow's Q&A format, as they are *way* too broad. See also: [ask]

Comment: Does this make more sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but it’s still too broad here. Questions here are generally expected to be about specific code-level issues you’re experiencing with code you’ve already written. Asking this style of question (asking for general pointers in the right direction, broad design guidance, etc.) are still considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: Is that any better

Comment: Unfortunately not - like I said, this site is primarily for questions around code *you’ve already written yourself* in order to meet your requirements, not for broad design inquiries without any code having already been written.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider. Askers are expected to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us the problems they are facing. Please also review the How to ask section for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site. Goodluck and happy coding :D

Comment: Oh ok I have code i just didnt put it because i thought it could be done without i will change to have the code now

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it!

There is a JS library called [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs).

And there is a link to the question approach
[How to simply export a Worksheet to xlsx?](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/817#issuecomment-331605640)